# How to get control and icon on the same line in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I am using bootstrap's grid system for page layout. In one of the column i want to show `input` control and font awesome icon in the same column side by side. However i am not able to get icon aligned properly. it always goes below the control.

Here is the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z8d0w4qz/1/)

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is that your not using form classes of bootstrap correctly. Bootstrap gives you ability to use it's form based classes and font awesome classes to design specifically. You can use the following html and bootstrap classes to achieve this.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="input-group">
          <input name="FirstName" class="form-control" id="FirstName" type="text">
          <span class="input-group-addon">
              <i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.input-group-addon {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: red;
}
```

If you want to remove the background and bordering that joins the icon to the input then just change the `.input-group-addon {` css class to following.

```
.input-group-addon {
     cursor: pointer;
     color: red;
     border-radius: 4px;
     border: 0px;
     background-color: transparent;
}
```

Sample: http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/VmvBXV

Answer (score 0):

`float:left` is what you are looking for here. Just apply it to both the input and the icon's class and set the input's width so that it doesn't take up the whole width of the screen.

```
.mt-remove {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
  float: left;
}
.mt-remove:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: "\f056";
  font-size: 12px;
}
#FirstName {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
```

Adding `line-height` on the `mt-remove` class might help you out also, if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Grid system is based on a 12 column layout. You currently have two elements inside one 6 column.

Try two 6 columns instead:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">input</div>
<div class="col-md-6">icon</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will definitly align the two side by side, but I'm not sure this is what OP wants. This looks like two parts of what will be a single input control so they should probably be in the same column. Just my two cents.

Comment: Upon looking at the question again you may be right. (Well, at least it gives an alternative to the other answer) -

Comment: Yup. You are definitly correct about the one `col-md-6` column though; it should be `col-md-12`